# 'tree' was not declared in this scope (C++)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am getting the following errors in CodeBlocks:

> 'originalTree' was not declared in this scope

and

> 'otherTree' was not declared in this scope

How do I fix them?

Here's my source code:

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class BST
{
    private:
        struct tree_node
        {
           tree_node* left;
           tree_node* right;
           T data;
        };
        tree_node* root;
    public:
        BST()
        {
           root = NULL;
        }
        ~BST()
        {
           Destroy(root);
        }
        void Destroy(tree_node* &tree)
        {
           if(tree != NULL)
           {
              Destroy(tree->left);
              Destroy(tree->right);
              delete tree;
           }
        }

        BST(const BST<T>& otherTree)
        {
           if(otherTree.root == NULL) //otherTree is empty
              root = NULL;
           else
              CopyTree(root, originalTree.root);
        }

        void CopyTree(tree_node* &copy, tree_node* originalTree)
        {
           if(originalTree == NULL)
           copy = NULL;
           else
           {
                  copy = new tree_node*;
                  copy->data = originalTree->data;
                  CopyTree(copy->left, originalTree->left);
                  CopyTree(copy->right, originalTree->right);
           }
        }

        const BST<T>& operator=(const BST<T>&)
        {
            if(this != &otherTree) //avoid self-copy
            {
               if(root != NULL)  //if the binary tree is not empty,
                                 //destroy the binary tree
               destroy(root);

               if(otherTree.root == NULL) //otherTree is empty
                  root = NULL;
               else
                  copyTree(root, otherTree.root);
            }//end else
            return *this;
        }

        bool isInTree(T);
        bool isEmpty() const { return root==NULL; }
        void print_postorder();
        void postorder(tree_node*);
        void add(T);
        void remove(T);
};
```

Comment: Because they are not declared in the class nor are they parameters for all the methods in which they are used. In this case, the error message fully described the problem.

Comment: where's defined otherTree inside operator=?

Comment: adding nonse letters at the end in order to bypass the "it looks like your post is mostly code" rule is not the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the assignment operator you are using `otherTree` without declaring it anywhere. In the copy constructor you forgot to declare `originalTree`.

This is very basic debugging and one of the very few cases in which the compiler error fully described the problem. If you don't try to debug your programs on your own, you'll never learn.